# Can every compact subset of $\Bbb R^n$ be written as a disjoint union of compact subsets, where each of them are path-connected?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

I was wondering if every compact subset of $\Bbb R^n$ could be written as a disjoint union of compact subsets, where each of them are path-connected, i.e. :

If $X \subset \Bbb R^n$, $n \ge 1$, $X$ is compact, then there exists a finite (or infinite) collection of compact sets $U_i,$ $i= 1, 2, ...$, such that each $U_i$ is path-connected (i.e. $\forall x, y \in U_i$, there exists $\gamma : [0, 1] \rightarrow U_i$ continuous such that $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\gamma(1) = y$), $X = \bigcup_i U_i$, and $U_i \cap U_j = \varnothing$ if $i \ne j$.

I don't really know if this is true and how one could prove it. If it is not, do you have any counterexample(s) ?

Comment: Every set can be written as a disjoint union of one-point sets, which are compact and path-connected.

Comment: Assuming you want the collection to be at most countably infinite, this is already false for $\mathbb R^1$. Consider the Cantor set, which is compact. It contains no intervals, hence its only connected subsets are singletons. And since the Cantor set is uncountable, it cannot be decomposed as a disjoint union of countably many connected subsets.

Comment: In $\mathbb R^2$ the closure of the set $\{(x,\sin\frac1x):0\lt x\le1\}$ can't be written as a countable disjoint union of path-connected closed sets.